# Linux + Windows booting options

Tags: linux, windows, hypervisor

What I've done in the past is simply Dual boot, but I would like to not have to reboot my computer in order to switch OS's. Specifically, what I'd like is:
Computer would mainly run Linux,
When I want to play a Windows only game I can switch over to Windows, for that period of time then return to Linux.
Both Linux and Windows need to run up to native in speed.

I'm looking for suggestions in setting this up.

I've looked into Xen, however, I hear that Xen doesn't support 3D graphics? is this accurate. I've also looked into WineD3D and VMGL. However, Wine won't play every game, so I'd still need the Windows VM, and VMGL doesn't seem to work universally either.

I'm running two different machines that I plan to put this setup on:
Laptop:
  Intel i7 4720HQ
  16GB Ram
  NVIDIA GeForce GTX 965M
Desktop:
  AMD FX-8350
  16GB Ram
  EVGA GeForce GTX 960

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score -1):

I just joined and the "Tour" said, don't ask questions that could lead to a discussion than an answer. Anyway, If gaming is your primary goal, have windows as primary boot & dive into linux as VM. Otherwise  you need to find a hyper-visor that provides 3D services or pass-through to your actual GPU.

[There is a discussion here](http://www.tomshardware.co.uk/answers/id-3073814/virtual-machine-gaming.html)